# SignalR Error loading hubs. How to handle when service is down

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I have a `SignalR` application that is a `Self-Hosted Windows Service Hub`.

My javascript client have in the index.html:

```
<script src="http://localhost:8080/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

But the Windows Service it not always running. So if it's not running and I try to load index.html I get the error:

```
Uncaught Error: SignalR: Error loading hubs. Ensure your hubs reference is correct, e.g. <script src='/signalr/js'></script>.
```

And makes sense because it wont find the javascript file until the Windows Service is running.

So my question is, how can I make it flexible so I don't get any error if the Windows Service is not running (localhost:8080).

Any clue?

Answer (score 3):

The solution was to load it dynamically using jQuery:

```
 $.getScript("http://localhost:8080/signalr/hubs")
            .done(function(script, textStatus) {


                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that SignalR is always mapped to the root path and the HTML including the hubs script is always running on the endpoint as SignalR, you should be able to use a root-relative path:

```
<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

Comment: The solution was to load it dynamically.